# Triangle (void in the inside) pattern print

Tags: go

Good morning guys, I wanted to ask you help for an exercise that is literally driving me crazy... I should print a triangle of n lines with (n - r) asterisks, but with an empty center. So an exercise with nested loops.

if we had n == 5, it would be something like this:

```
*****
*  *
* *
**
*
```

I tried with this one:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Print("Inserire n: ")
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    
    for r := 0; r < n; r++ {                                    // r == line
        for a := 0; a < n - r; a++ {                            // a == asterisk
            fmt.Print("*")
            if r > 0 || r < n - 1 {       
                for s := 0; s < (n - (3 + r) +1); s++ {         // s == space
                    fmt.Print(" ")
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("")
    } 
}
```

My output for n == 5 looks like this:

```
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
**
*
```

There are 2 problems that I cannot really understand how to solve:

1. Why does the first line of asterisks have spaces if I put as a condition that r must be greater than 0 and less than n-1?
2. How do you prevent unnecessary asterisks, but only spaces, from being printed on the other lines (r)?

Comment: You need to treat the first line differently from the others.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the first line of asterisks have spaces if I put as a condition that r must be greater than 0 and less than n-1?

You are correct in that "greater than 0 **and** less than n-1" would give you what you need but that is not what your statement currently is (`if r > 0 || r < n - 1` - `||` = `OR` not `AND`).

> How do you prevent unnecessary asterisks, but only spaces, from being printed on the other lines (r)?

Currently you have three levels of loops which makes the algorithm more complex than it needs to be:

1. Lines
2. Asterisks
3. Spaces

You only really need two levels (lines and columns). With this approach you just need to make a decision for each position - do I output `*` or  . Pseudo code for this follows (have left a few bits for you to fill in):

```golang
for a := 0; a < n-r; a++ { // a == column
    if [Firstline] || [first column] || [last column] { 
        fmt.Print("*")
    } else {
        fmt.Print(" ")
    }
}
```

From comments:

> why is the last condition a == n - r -1?

Consider the loop `a := 0; a < n-r; a++`; if `n-r == 5` then `a` will range from `0` to `4` (inclusive - [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4ySTxvg7bTR)). This means that the last value (column) will be 4 (`n-r-1`). You could change the loop to `a := 1; a <= n-r; a++` in which case `n - r` would be the last column.

Comment: I got it correctly. The problem is that I still don't understand one thing... why is the last condition a == n - r -1? Shouldn't it be EXACTLY n-r (like where the asterisk should be printed)? Why that -1??

Comment: @BitcoinBanksNoLongerNeeded I have updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! @Brits